# How to open a directory in the default file manager from Matlab?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, directory

I am working on a GUI which has to work on different OS : Windows, Unix, Mac… and I wonder how to open a directory by pressing a pushbutton ?

Is there any general command to open it in the default file manager ? (Finder for Mac, Explorer for Windows, Nautilus for Unix with GNOME etc.)

I am not trying to just display the informations of the selected folder (ls, cd & dir do not help me).

Thank you in advance,

Benjamin.

Answer (score 2):

use [`uigetdir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uigetdir.html) to open a dialog box for selection a folder

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on opening the actual file manager (and not one of the cross-platform Java dialogs accessible from Matlab), you can use something like this:

```
% Just as an example; current dir
myDir = '.';

% Windows PC    
if ispc
    C = evalc(['!explorer ' myDir]);

% Unix or derivative
elseif isunix

    % Mac
    if ismac
        C = evalc(['!open ' myDir]);

    % Linux
    else
        fMs = {...
            'xdg-open'   % most generic one
            'gvfs-open'  % successor of gnome-open
            'gnome-open' % older gnome-based systems               
            'kde-open'   % older KDE systems
           };
        C = '.';
        ii = 1;
        while ~isempty(C)                
            C = evalc(['!' fMs{ii} ' ' myDir]);
            ii = ii +1;
        end

    end
else
    error('Unrecognized operating system.');
end

if ~isempty(C)
    error(['Error while opening directory in default file manager.\n',...
        'The reported error was:\n%s'], C); 
end
```

Note that the closest thing most Linux distributions have to a default file manager is passing the directory to the `XXX-open` command. This captures many Linux users, but certainly not all of them. For better Linux support, you'd have to write a lot more elaborate system commands to find out the default file manager.

But I'll leave that up to you :)

Comment: Thanky you Rody, that's the solution I was thinking about before asking on SO. If there is no function to do that, I will create mine.